# AWS Glue crawler exclude patterns not working

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have following AWS S3 bucket and folders:

I want to crawl the 3 parquet files under folder1 and folder2 (one in folder1 and 2 in folder2) under tfsdl_apac_test/rz_test. Folder1 and2 each contain a _default_log and _symlink_format_manifest folders and they have same files for both folder1 and folder2 for testing purpose and the contents in _default_log and _symlink_format_manifest are shown here for folder1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the crawler settings:
[image]

But the crawler gives me this result in the generated tables: all the files from all the subfolders under rz_test. There are total of 13 files from all the subfolders.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The information from official document is a little misleading, the exclude pattern should be:

```
    **/_delta_log/**
    **/_symlink_format_manifest/**
```